# select the row between two dates in another table

Tags: oracle

i have table A which has three column name,app,date
and table b which has three column name,start,end

how i could write a query  that return only the name which has the date  came between start an end in the table b ?

Comment: From your question, it isn't apparent what's the purpose of table A (because name and dates are both in B). Anyways, if you want to connect the name with the `app` column, google for "sql join".

Answer (score 0):

```
select name from A inner join B on (A.date between B.start and B.end)
```